# How to create foreign keys in Laravel without errors

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel. However, when I migrate my table using Artisan, I am thrown the following error.

```
Schema::create('billing_transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('payment_amount')->default(0);
    $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
    $table->foreignIdFor(PatientVisit::class)->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreignIdFor(BillingInvoice::class)->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('created_by_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('updated_by_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
> (SQL: alter table `billing_transactions` add constraint
> `billing_transactions_billing_invoice_id_foreign` foreign key
> (`billing_invoice_id`) references `billing_invoices` (`id`) on delete
> cascade on update cascade)

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use foreignId instead of foreignIdFor? (like you're doing with your created_by_id)

Comment: Are the tables all using InnoDB? I think MyISAM tables don't let you reference them in foreign key constraints

Comment: And have you already created the billing_invoices table?

Comment: Yes its still persists even when I use the "foreignId". When I get rid of the "contrained()" function, the migrations run with success. But I need the constrained to work.

Comment: Is the primary key of the biling_invoices an int(11) in the database?

Comment: Yes please the primary key is int. It is quiet funny how I have implemented the same procedure in various places, and all works, just this particular one.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `nullable` call? I think from memory foreign constraints can't be null

Comment: Ok I will remove the nullable and see. But check something funny, the "PatientVisit" has nullable and it works fine.

Comment: I just removed the nullable(), it still did not work. The only time it works is if i remove the contrained(). But I need it to be there. Hmm.

Comment: perhaps your table is not empty, and constraint is not met, try to check for broken foreign ids in your records

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->BigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->BigInteger('lang_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->BigInteger('reference_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->boolean('blocked')->default(0);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('lang_id')->references('id')->on('languages')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('reference_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['role_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('role_id');
        $table->dropForeign(['lang_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('lang_id');
        $table->dropForeign(['reference_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('reference_id');
        $table->dropUnique(['email']);
        $table->dropColumn('email');
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

I use like that. For foreigns and uniques.